# WebApi Get Request Binding to Complex Type

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

My Clients Controller has:

```
public IHttpActionResult Get([FromUri]PagingOptions pagingOptions, [FromUri]string searchText = null)
{
    //...
```

And the class is defined as:

```
public class PagingOptions
{
    public int PageIndex = 0;
    public int PageSize = 100;
}
```

Yet I get 0 & 100 with:

```
GET clients?pageSize=2&pageIndex=0
```

If I make the controller method:

```
public IHttpActionResult Get([FromUri]int pageIndex, [FromUri]int pageSize, [FromUri]string searchText = null)
{
    //...
```

Then it works fine.

What's wrong? I've got the `FromURI` attribute in place (as most other questions don't have)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For correct binding - specify properties instead of fields.
For default values - set them into constructor

```
public class PagingOptions
{
    public PagingOptions()
    {
        PageIndex = 0;
        PageSize = 100;
    }
    public int PageIndex {get;set;}
    public int PageSize {get;set;}
}
```